# ARM7 ViSUAL Emulator and Keil uVision4

Tags: embedded, keil, arm7

There are two questions about  ARM7 ViSUAL EMulator and Keil uVision4.

- Run this on the ARM7 ViSUAL Emulator and explain what it does.
- Consider how the variables Value1, Value2, Value3 and Result have been declared. Explain why this would not compile using Keil uVision4.

I have run the code but I still don't understand what it does.

```
 Main
  LDR r1, =Value1 
  LDR R2, =Value2 
  LDR r1,[r1]
  LDR r2,[r2]
Return
  ANDS R3, R1,R2 
  BNE SEND 
  BEQ NEXT 
  END
SEND
  LDR r4, =Result 
  LDR r4,[r4] 
  STR r3, [r4] 
  END
NEXT
   MOV R1, R2 
   LDR R2, =Value3 
   LDR R2, [r2]
   B       Return
   END
 Value1 DCD &0202
 Value2 DCD  &0101
 Value3 DCD &0001
 Result DCD  &FFFFFFF0
```

[image: Result on the ARM7 Emulator]

Comment: Pedantically: It would not "compile" because it is _assembly_; it needs to be _assembled_ not _compiled_.

Answer (score 2):

The memory allocations (`DCD`) are done in the same area as the code declaration. Which means that it probably will be used as if `AREA PROGRAM, CODE, READONLY` was set and as such keil won't assemble it. It also means that if it was assembled the data locations will be `READONLY`. A proper declaration of variables would be preceded by `AREA <a section name>, DATA, READWRITE`

```
 Main
  LDR R1, =Value1 -- load Value1 inside R1
  LDR R2, =Value2 -- load Value2 inside R2
  LDR R1,[R1]  -- load indirect the address pointed to by the value of R1 to R1 -- (I have reservations about the functionality of this code)
  LDR R2,[R2]  -- load indirect the address pointed to by the value of R2 to R2 -- (I have reservations about the functionality of this code)
Return
  ANDS R3, R1,R2 -- R3 = R1 AND R2
  BNE SEND -- branch if not equal to SEND label
  BEQ NEXT -- branch to NEXT if equal
  END 
SEND
  LDR R4, =Result -- load Result to R4
  LDR R4,[R4]  -- load indirect the address pointed to by the value of R4 to R4 -- (I have reservations about the functionality of this code)
  STR R3, [R4] -- store indirect to address pointed to by the value of R4 with the value of R3
  END
NEXT
   MOV R1, R2  -- copy R2 to R1
   LDR R2, =Value3  -- load Value3 to R2
   LDR R2, [R2] -- load indirect the address pointed to by the value of R2 to R2 -- (I have reservations about the functionality of this code)
   B       Return -- unconditional branch to Return label
   END
 Value1 DCD &0202  -- word allocation with hex value of 
 Value2 DCD &0101  -- word allocation with hex value of 
 Value3 DCD &0001  -- word allocation with hex value of 
 Result DCD &FFFFFFF0 -- word allocation with hex value of
```

This code tries to save the fact that `r2` and `r1` are equal or an infinite loop will occur because of the static nature of the values saved inside `Value<1-3>`